# Json cannot read property of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I execute a command (the error doesn't occur when I type a normal message) in my discord bot I get an error saying:

> Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

And it occurs when I try to console log an object from a json file where I store users data.

Those are the first lines of code of the index.js file of my bot, the line where I try to console log is where the error occurs

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const prefix = '>';

let xp = require("./storage/dbGeneral.json");
let pr = require("./storage/dbPremium.json");
let lv = require("./storage/levels.json");

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(pr[message.author.id].active);
}
```

This is the json file where I store the data

```
{
  "397387465024864257": {
    "active": false,
    "dateStart": "",
    "dateEnd": ""
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
index.js:14
    console.log(pr[message.author.id].active);
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined
    at Client.client.on.message (index.js:14:39)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

I really don't know what is the cause of the error, all other json requests work fine with the same method.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195883/discussion-on-question-by-gb-factory-json-cannot-read-property-of-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by trying to access a property of something not defined.
To fix your problem, you must check if the user exists in your database.

```
let user = pr[message.author.id];
if(user) console.log(user.active)
```